# Draw Pivot Lines until Cross and Close above/below

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I tried changing the Script, adding if-conditions with ta.crossover / ta.crossunder functions but nothing works.
the idea is pretty simple, i have a script that is drawing pivot high and low points as lines, everytime a new pivot point is detected it starts drawing a new line.
i would need to add one more condition to ONLY draw new lines if there is a cross and close above or below.

For Example: Pivot High is detected, there are new Pivot Highs detected; but because the price did not close above the actually printed Line, the new Pivot High Line will not be plottet on the Chart.

Opposite for Pivot Low Lines, only "search" for a new pivot low if the price crossed and closed below the actual one.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='Pivot Lines', overlay=true)
//

leftBars = input(5, title='Left Bars ')
rightBars = input(5, title='Right Bars')

//
highUsePivot = fixnan(ta.pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)[1])
lowUsePivot = fixnan(ta.pivotlow(leftBars, rightBars)[1])
r1 = plot(highUsePivot, color=ta.change(highUsePivot) ? na : #FF0000, linewidth=1, offset=-(rightBars + 1), title='Pivot High')
s1 = plot(lowUsePivot, color=ta.change(lowUsePivot) ? na : #233dee, linewidth=1, offset=-(rightBars + 1), title='Pivot Low')
```

Comment: by definition, your pivot high is higher than the 5 previous and 5 next bars. So how will a bar close above ?

Comment: you are right, but imo it should work as it is only used to detect the levels.

Comment: @G.Lebret please do you have any ideas / suggestions for a workaround? something that can help me find a solution? i applied the darvas box indicator (not open source) and i think it is using pivots or highest/lowest highs/lows and this box continues being printed until a candle is closed above or below this box, for me this indicates that there is a solution for this :). thank you